# Draw a horizontal line with just a click using Adobe Photoshop

Tags: image-processing, photoshop, photoshop-script

I am looking to find a way to draw a horizontal line of full page width on a PNG file with a single click. Thing is I am trying to draw a lot of lines and if I've to click and drag it becomes extremely inefficient.

I am working on a Windows platform.

How can I achieve this using Adobe Photoshop? Any ideas?

Thanks

Here is a sample of page. Green lines are the ones drawn.
[image]

Comment: I suspect you might be better off looking for an image annotation tool rather than paying Adobe for Photoshop. You can do it quite easily in Python, if that is an option? And even combine it with your other question about cutting images along the lines you draw.

Comment: You can try to do this:
1. Make a full copy of the folder with image files.
2. In any graphics editor, in the place where the lines are needed to put points.
3. Using a script (cmd, bash) with Imagemagick, comparing the picture with the dots and the original picture, draw green lines.

Comment: @AlexAlex I think your suggestion is probably the best suggestion I've received so far. 
I'll attempt this method - Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Draw a line as you want it on a big new canva. Trim the image when done. Then Create a brush from the open file (edit > define brush preset), save it, done. Now you can use yout line as a brush.